# TwitteR unable to get PIN

Tags: r, twitter

I am unable to get a PIN when trying to access the twitter app via R (TwitteR). When it gives me the URL and asks for the PIN, the URL just points to my website (in Chrome). In Safari and Firefox, the website says "SSL is required". I don't have any error messages in the console; however, I don't know where to get the PIN at this point (I've searched all over). Appreciate any help.

From what I can tell, I have all the settings in the Twitter app set up correctly.

```
    download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
    library(RCurl) 
    # Set SSL certs globally (I tried this after it didn't work without it) 
    options(RCurlOptions = list(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")))

    reqURL <- "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"
    accessURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"
    authURL <- "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
    consumerKey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    consumerSecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
                         consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
                         requestURL=reqURL,
                         accessURL=accessURL,
                         authURL=authURL)
    twitCred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))
```

Comment: same problem here. Did you fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the protocol of the link returned by handshake to https (it is http by default).